# On real algebraic numbers with all powers of same degree

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In my research I need to find an explicit example of an $n$-degree real algebraic number $\alpha$, for which $\alpha^k$ has degree $n$, for all $k\geq 1$.

I thought $\alpha:=1+\sqrt[n]{2}$ was enough, but I am not being able to prove it.

Someone could kindly help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to find one example for each $n$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, for each $n$, an $n$-degree algebraic number for which every its positive powers have the same degree, namely, $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

I don't know what you mean by EXPLICIT, but here is an example.

Let $\alpha$ be a real root of $f=X^n-X-1$ (there is always one).

Then it is known that $f$ is irreducible over the  rationals, with galois group $S_n$. Let $L/Q$ be the splitting field of $f$. The subfield $K=Q(\alpha)$ has degree $n$, so it corresponds to a subgroup of $S_n$ of index $n$. Such subgroup is maximal ( at least, it is true for $n\neq 6$, since in this case subgroups of index $n$ are conjugate to the stabilizer of a point)). In particular, $K/Q$ has no notrivial subfields.

Thus, if you manage to prove that $\alpha^k$ is not rational for any $k\geq 1$, then you will get $Q(\alpha^k)=K$ and $\alpha^k$ has degree $n$ for all $k$. But $\alpha^k$ cannot be rational for some $k$. Otherwise, the Galois group of $L$ would be solvable, which is not the case for $n\geq 5$ , and i think you can manage by hand for $n=2,3,4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Explicit means that $\alpha$ should be a finite algebraic combination of algebraic numbers. Examples with Galois theory or even less as root of polynomials are easy to find.